# How do you use the JIT C/C++ UDF in MonetDB

Tags: c++, odbc, user-defined-functions, jit, monetdb

I am new to MonetDB, and want to write an SQL query in C++ that includes a C++ function as shown in the link below, but I'm not sure how to actually do this.

https://www.monetdb.org/index.php/blog/JIT_C_C%252B%252B_UDFs_in_MonetDB

If I set up an ODBC connection can I send the function along with the SQL query via the ODBC connection or is there a different method that I need to implement to be able to do this.
Sorry I'm struggling to make sense of the MonetDB documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the whole `CREATE FUNCTION ...(...) LANGUAGE ...` is just a normal SQL query. You can send it in your ODBC (or any other client drivers) the same way you send other SQL queries.

However, please be aware that the JIT C/C++ UDF is an experimental feature and not actively maintained.  For better maintenance, please use the examples in this repository for how to extend MonetDB with your own C/C++ functions: https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB-extend. You can clone it with `hg clone https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/MonetDB-extend`.

Comment: I had a look at the MonetDB-extend functionality which led me to the following tutorial. https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/ServerProgramming/ExtendingSQL/UserDefinedFunctions    From this tutorial it looks like the reverse function is already set up in the source.  Step 7 in the tutorial says that you have to call the bootstrap program then the normal configure/make/make install.  I can't find the bootstrap program, can you please advise where i can find it.  Also if I run bootstrap will the reverse udf become available as  it looks like the reverse udf setup is complete in the code.

Comment: `bootstrap` is to compile MonetDB source code before the Oct2020 version; it's a programme included in the source code.  If you use Oct2020 or newer, you use `cmake`.  We still need to update the documentation on how to build MonetDB with CMake.

Comment: thank you for your feedback.  I cant get the reverse UDF function working, but ill post it in a new question.